# How to add variables to path on Windows?

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, virtual-environment

On page 13 of Python Automation Cookbook,

Then, add the following variables to your sheet startup script, these normally
being `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. The virtual environments will be installed
under the WORKON_HOME directory instead of the same directory as the project, as
shown previously:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`enter code here`
```

This book supposes readers are using the Linux system. I don't know how can I do it under windows.

I search "Edit the system environment variables"

[image]

Click on the "Environment Variables" button and then click on the "New" button under "System Variables", it gives me

[image]

What should I fill in these blanks?